# Get parent page custom fields to footer in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have different footer content for every parent page. I have about 8 parent pages. How can I still use parent page custom fields when navigating to child pages. Example: Parent page -> Child page -> Child page.

```
<?php
#footer block
$footer_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_footer_block_title', true);
$footer_content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_footer_block_text', true)); ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 footer-col-1">
<h2 class="footer-title"><?php echo $footer_title; ?></h2>
<?php echo $footer_content; ?>
</div> ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven´t tested this, but i think this should work;

```
    <?php
    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
        $root=count($ancestors)-1;
        $parent = $ancestors[$root];
    } else {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    }

    $footer_title = get_post_meta($parent, '_cmb_footer_block_title', true);
    $footer_content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($parent, '_cmb_footer_block_text', true)); ?>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 footer-col-1">
      <h2 class="footer-title"><?php echo $footer_title; ?></h2>
      <?php echo $footer_content; ?>
   </div>
```